# How to copy an entire DB in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Our clients do not have admin access to our web servers and we run MVC  , how can i clone an existing DB  to fork the data without  shutting down the current DB ?. At the moment EF creates the new DB but all the records need to be manually created so we wanted to do a fork.

I suppose i could go through all entities in all tables , detach them all and insert into the DB but is there a nicer way ? As writing that code for 100 tables is not quick even if we use reflection .

The other option of doing a backup and restore is a bit painful as some of the DBs are hosted on SQL server and some as attached files .

Ben

Comment: How about import/export data wizard?

Comment: You want to move an existing db to another Db?

Comment: import export , requires admin accesss - this is done via the web ..

Answer (score 2):

EF is not tool for this. Either use native SQL tools like backup / restore or if there is any additional logic needed create SSIS package or custom ADO.NET application for data migration. With EF it will not only take long to do that but it will be also terrible bad and slow solution.